# save an instance of class in global variable in order to resotre the class (creating a "backup")

Tags: c++, class, global-variables

sorry if I'm not clear, I'm new in this.
I will give rare background:
I got a class called Restaurant which has those fields:

```
bool open;
std::vector<Table*> tables;
std::vector<Dish> menu;
std::vector<BaseAction*> actionsLog;
```

where Table,Dish and BaseAction are also classes.

I have been asked to create a global variable which will hold a "backup" for the Restaurant, which means that I can restore it in any time using this global variable.

my first thought is that building a good copy constructor for Restaurant will make the job. but after thinking about it, I was not sure what the backup in the global variable will contain. I will try to explain, the Instance of the restaurant holds some fields  that their information is not allocated dynamically, where this information is saved? how I can restore it? **does the fact that I save it in global variable means that all information (in heap and stack) is avilable in any scope?**

Those question made me ask you what is the right way of doing it, and how it's working?

Again sorry if saying wrong things. if I'm, please correct me.

Comment: Without further information about the classes `Table`, `Dish`, `BaseAction`, we cannot really help you. Please provide a MCVE. Can you change the layout of `Restaurant` (it currently is actually rather poor as it involves raw pointers)? If `Table` and `BaseAction` have a (virtual) method `clone()` that returns an identical `Table`/`BaseAction`, you can use those to make deep copies of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct to create a copy constructor is correct.

Indeed, if you do this properly, the rest of your question is moot.

To "backup" your variable (i.e. create a copy of it), all its state must be recreated.

That means, all its direct members, by deep copy … which in turns means all the elements pointed-to by your vectors will also need to be cloned.

This is going to be messy; it would be less so if you did not store raw pointers in containers — in fact, if the containers didn't store pointers at all, you could just let the compiler-generated copy constructor do the job for you:

```
Restaurant backup = myMainRestaurant;
```

Admittedly this is not feasible if your `Table` and `BaseAction` are bases of an inheritance hierarchy (which they appear to be).

I would not advise making this a global variable, though; you're going to have all manner of lifetime issues with that. Your best bet is probably more dynamic allocation (ugh):

```
Restaurant* backup = nullptr;

int main()
{
    Restaurant myMainRestaurant;
    // ...

    backup = new Restaurant(myMainRestaurant);
    // ...

    delete backup;
 }
```

I'd recommend smart pointers but my own instinct is that you're in education and that this won't be accepted (sad!).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you failed to provide details of the classes `Table`, `Dish`, and `BaseAction`. I presume, therefore, that `Dish` and `Table` are non-polymorphic classes, while `BaseAction` is a polymorphic base class with layout

```
struct BaseAction
{
    virtual BaseAction* clone() const = 0;  // make a copy on the heap
    /* more virtual methods irrelevant to this post */
    virtual ~BaseAction() {}
};
```

and that Restaurant is essentially a C-style struct. Then, a backup could be as follows

```
std::unique_ptr<Restaurant> make_backup(Restaurant const&restaurant)
{
    auto backup = make_unique(new Restaurant);
    backup->tables.reserve(restaurant.tables.size());
    for(auto t : restaurant.tables)
        backup->tables.push_back(new Table(*t));       // copy tables
    backup.menu = restaurant.menu;                     // copy menu
    backup->actionsLog.reserve(restaurant.actionsLog.size());
    for(auto a : restaurant.actionsLog)
        backup->actionsLog.push_back(a->clone());      // copy actions
    return backup;
}
```